# Filter the list of tables that start with a specific name

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I get the list of tables in the dataset using the below command. I wonder whether there is a way to filter the tables that start with a name 'Acura' and then store the result in an array? I do not find any filter methods if i try filtering the tables returned. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 list = bq.DataSet('bigdatatest:carlist')

 for x in list:
  print x
```

This for loop prints a list of tables. I have to filter this list such that I get the tables that start with name 'Acura' and store that list in an array.

I have a list like below - from this i have filter the tables that begin with 'Acura'

```
test:SF.AcuraUsage_20150311
test:SF.AcuraUsage_20150312
test:SF.AcuraUsage_20150313
test:SF.AcuraUsage_20150314
test:SF.AcuraUsage_20150315
test:SF.AcuraUsage_20150316
test:SF.AcuraUsage_20150317
test:SF.ClientUsage_20150318
test:SF.ClientUsage_20150319
test:SF.ClientUsage_20150320
test:SF.ClientUsage_20150321
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[item for item in list if str(item).startswith('test:SF.Acura')]
```

Comment: Is this a for loop?

Comment: Yes, it is a for loop

Comment: @KHELILIHamza: I have provided my list in the question. Will this for loop work if i have to filter the tables that begin with Acura?